# Problems splitting and searching array segments with pthreads

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading

I'm working on a personal project to fill an array with random numbers, split into a number of user defined segments using pthread (POSIX), search for a target in each segment, and return the number of times the target was found. I'm having bugs and issues. For more than one thread, issues like the target not being held in the struct member and a thread not being created and other things happen. I'm sure my logic is off and my code and it's output reflect this, but I'm stumped. How would you split an array into threads? What logic am I messing up?

HEADER FILE...

```
#ifndef COUNT_ARRAY_H
#define COUNT_ARRAY_H


// structure declarations
typedef struct
{
 int     threadNum;
 int     *array;
 int     first;
 int     last;
 int     target;
 int     numFound;

} ThreadInfo;


// function prototypes
void*   ThreadFunc(void  *vptr);


#endif  // COUNT_ARRAY_H
```

MAIN FILE....

```
 #include    <pthread.h>
 #include    <stdio.h>
 #include    <stdlib.h>
 #include    "count_array.h"

 int     main(void)
 {
  int                 numSegs;
  int                 numSegElems;
  int                 maxRand;
  int                 target;
  int                 totalElems;
  int                 totalFound = 0;
  ThreadInfo          *infoPtr;
  pthread_t           *threadHandles;
  int                 index = 0;
  int                 first;
  int                 last;
  int                 threadNum = 0;

//get primary info from user...
printf(" Please enter the total number of elements? ");
scanf("%d", &totalElems);

printf(" Please enter the maximum random value: ");
scanf("%d", &maxRand);

printf(" Please enter the number of segments (1 to 15857): ");
scanf("%d", &numSegs);

 if(numSegs > 15857)
   {
    puts(" Too many segments for machine!");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

 numSegElems = totalElems/numSegs;

// configure the array to work with
// declare array here...

 int myArray[totalElems];

//and fill array here
for(; index < totalElems; index++)
   {
    // % rand() and maxRand to get good range and
    //not go beyond users max number
    myArray[index] = (rand() % maxRand);

    //test printf...ignore if still here
    printf(" %d \n", myArray[index]);
   }

// get the target value to look for
 printf(" Please enter the target value: ");
 scanf("%d",&target);

// display initial information
printf("*** Begin search: target = %d, # elements = %d, # segments = %d, "
                                            "# segment elements = %d\n"
                                                            , target
                                                            , totalElems
                                                            , numSegs
                                                            , numSegElems);

// initialize the array first/last indexes into the integer array
  if(numSegs == 1)
    {
     first = totalElems;
     last = 0;
    }
  else
    {
     first = totalElems - numSegElems;
     last = (first - numSegElems);
    }
// allocate an array to store the thread handles

   int size; //size of segment
   if(numSegs > 1)
     {

      size = numSegElems;
     }
   else
     {
      size = totalElems;
     }

    //test printf...please ignore if still here
    //printf(" size %d \n", size);

     int segA[size];//not sure if I need this

// loop and create threads (# of segments)
index = 0;

for(; threadNum < numSegs; index++)
{
    // allocate a thread info structure from the heap
    threadHandles = calloc(totalElems, sizeof(pthread_t));
    infoPtr = calloc(totalElems, sizeof(ThreadInfo));

    // store the information in the allocated structure

      infoPtr[index].threadNum = threadNum;

      infoPtr->target = target;
      infoPtr->first = first;
      infoPtr->last = last;
      infoPtr->array = myArray;


    // create the secondary thread, passing the thread info
      pthread_create(&threadHandles[index], NULL, ThreadFunc, &infoPtr[index]);

    // update the first/last array indexes for the next thread

      first = last;
      last = first-numSegs;
      ++threadNum;
}

// loop and join the threads to fetch each thread's results
  for(index = 0; index < numSegs; index++)
     {
      // join with the next thread
      pthread_join(threadHandles[index], NULL);

      // get the total number of matches from the thread's infoPtr

      // and display a message
      printf(" *** pthread_join returned: threadNum = %d, numFound = %d\n",
                                     infoPtr[index].threadNum, infoPtr->numFound);


     }
        // release the infoPtr structure back to the heap
          free(infoPtr);

// display the final results

// release heap memory
free(threadHandles);

return 0;

}  // end of "main"


void*   ThreadFunc(void  *vptr)
{
 //declare and set vars
 ThreadInfo *ptr = vptr;
 ptr->numFound = 0;
 int index = ptr->first-1;

 //test printf...ignore if still here
  printf(" Targ %d \n", ptr->target);

 //start search
 for(; index >= ptr->last; --index)
    {
      printf(" %d \n", ptr->array[index]);

    //if target found
     if(ptr->target ==  ptr->array[index])
       {
        puts(" Target found! ");
        //increment numFound
        ++ptr->numFound;
       }
    }

     //drop out and display message

}
```

Comment: You have no header file for `pthread_create` and `pthread_join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got multiple errors in your allocation of `threadHandles` and `infoPtr`.  First, you don't really want to be allocating `totalElems` of them -- you only need `numSegs`.  Second, and more crucially, you're reallocating them and changing the values of the pointers `infoPtr` and `threadHandles` every time through the thread invocation loop.  Third, you've mixed treating `infoPtr` as an array of `ThreadInfo` structures here:

```
  infoPtr[index].threadNum = threadNum;
```

with treating it as a pointer to a changing `ThreadInfo` structure here:

```
  infoPtr->target = target;
  infoPtr->first = first;
  infoPtr->last = last;
  infoPtr->array = myArray;
```

so every time through the loop, you're setting these parameters on the first thread only.

To fix this, edit and move the allocations before the loop and treat `infoPtr` consistently as an array:

```
threadHandles = calloc(numSegs, sizeof(pthread_t));
infoPtr = calloc(numSegs, sizeof(ThreadInfo));

for(; threadNum < numSegs; index++)
{
  infoPtr[index].threadNum = threadNum;

  infoPtr[index].target = target;
  infoPtr[index].first = first;
  infoPtr[index].last = last;
  infoPtr[index].array = myArray;
```

and also fix up the second use of `infoPtr` in this `printf` a little further down:

```
  printf(" *** pthread_join returned: threadNum = %d, numFound = %d\n",
               infoPtr[index].threadNum, infoPtr[index].numFound);
```

and things will work a little better.

There are still more bugs lingering in your setting of `first` and `last`.  I suggest you print out their values and make sure they are coming out the way you intend.  I was able to get them to become negative (and start searching random memory) pretty easily.

Comment: I see now. I was able to mostly fix the first and last, but there's an issue with pthread. The for loop will start, print out the first and last (so I can see what's inside every time), and then DOESN'T create a thread. It simply skips the pthread_create and goes back up to the top. I'm at a loss as to why this occurs. Should I try adding the allocation stuff at the bottom or top of the for loop?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. I wasn't incrementing my index and such. Thanks for your help!